# Select some from many binary sequences so that the result of "or" them together is 1111111111....111

Tags: algorithm

I have N binary sequences of length L, where N and L maybe very large, and those sequences maybe very sparse, say have much more 0s then 1s.

I want to select M sequences from them, namely b_1, b_2, b_3..., such that

```
b_1 | b_2 | b_3 ... | b_M = 1111...11 (L 1s)
```

Is there an algorithm to achieve it?

My idea is:

STEP1: for position from 1 to L, count the total number of sequences which has 1 at that position. Name it 'owning number'

STEP2: consider the position having minimum owning number, and choose the sequence having the maximum number of 1s from the owning sequence of that position.

STEP3: ignore the chosen sequence, update owning number and go back to STEP2.

I believe that my method cannot generate the best answer.

Does anyone has a better idea?

Comment: Do you mean selecting with random uniform probability? Or any selection can be the output?

Comment: The way you have currently framed the problem allows a given position to be covered by more than one b_i -- is that intended?

Comment: @Andrey..maybe I did not present clearly. I mean find an algorithm to find the optimal selection, not selecting randomly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the well known [set cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem). It is [NP-hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard) — in fact, its decision version is one of the canonical NP-complete problems and was among the 21 problems included in [Karp's 1972 paper](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~luca/cs172/karp.pdf) — and so no efficient algorithm is known for solving it.

The algorithm you describe in your question is known as the "[greedy algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover#Greedy_algorithm)" and (unless your problem has some special features that you are not telling us) it's essentially the best known approach. It finds a collection of sets that is no more than O(log |N|) times the size of the smallest such collection.

Comment: I'd say “best known approach *for large inputs* ”. For small inputs, where an exponential time algorithm is still feasible, computing the optimal solution might be worth that extra time.

Comment: @MvG: That's a fair point. (The OP does say that the inputs "may be very large".)

Comment: ..great.thank you! Now I only need to find an approximate solution.

Comment: Also, O(lg n)-approximations are probably [the best you can do](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Inapproximability_results).

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a typical [backtrack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) task.

Yes, your algoryth sounds reasonable if you want to have a good answer quickly. If you want to have the combination of the least possible samples you can't do better than try all combinations.

Comment: You can do slightly better using a branch-and-bound search.  It's the same as backtracking, except (in this context) you stop going deeper whenever you have an incomplete solution having k sets and a k-set complete solution has already been found earlier in the search.

Comment: My input size maybe very large, maybe n = 10000. Using backtrack costs too much. Actually, Gareth Rees points out it is NP-Hard, so using greedy algorithm to find a solution is enough to satisfy me.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the exact structure of the problem, there is an other technique that often works well (and actually gives an *optimal* result):

Let `x[j]` be a boolean variable representing the choice whether to include the j'th binary sequence in the result. A zero-suppressed binary decision diagram can now represent (maybe succinctly - depending on the characteristics of the problem) the family of sets such that the OR of the binary sequences corresponding to a variable `x[j]` included in the set is all ones. Finding the smallest such set (thus minimizing the number of sequences included) is relatively easy if the ZDD was succinct. Details can be found in The Art of Computer Programming chapter 7.1.4 (volume 4A).

It's also easy to adapt to an *exact* cover, by taking the family of sets such that there is exactly one 1 for every position.

Comment: maybe I did not present clearly, there is nothing involving probability. I mean find an algorithm to find the optimal selection, not selecting randomly.

Comment: @harold..sorry. I mistook your 'boolean variable' into 'random variable'..forgive me:)...